# How to create a ChoiceField for user email from EmailAddress model of allauth in django restframework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using django allauth and restframework in backend for API. My question is how can i create a ChoiceField in my serializer with the email addresses of the logged in user as values so that instead of a textfield the form will create a Select field for email field.

so far I have created a `AuthUserSerializer` serializer for my user API.

**users/serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from users.models import *

emails = [(email.email, email.email) for email in EmailAddress.objects.all()]

class AuthUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=emails)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'avatar',
            'bio', 'country', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_superuser', 'last_login',
            'date_joined')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'is_staff': { 'read_only': True },
            'is_superuser': { 'read_only': True },
            'last_login': { 'read_only': True },
            'date_joined': { 'read_only': True }
        }
```

I have initialized the email field as a `ChoiceField` in the above code and the choices are the emails got from the `EmailAddress` model.

But I want to get the emails created by the requested user. I don't know how to do it.

I tried creating a `CustomChoiceField` like below, but still it does not work.

```
class CustomChoiceField(serializers.ChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        user = self.context.get('request').user
        emails = [(email.email, email.email) for email in EmailAddress.objects.filter(user=user)]
        super().__init__(emails, **kwargs)

class AuthUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = ChoiceField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'avatar',
            'bio', 'country', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_superuser', 'last_login',
            'date_joined')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'is_staff': { 'read_only': True },
            'is_superuser': { 'read_only': True },
            'last_login': { 'read_only': True },
            'date_joined': { 'read_only': True }
        }
```

**users/views.py**

```
from base.views import CustomModelViewSet
from users.models import *
 
class AuthUserViewset(CustomModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AuthUserSerializer
    pagination_class = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = User.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id)
        return queryset
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong here.

**UPDATE**

The below image shows that the email field as a text input.

[image]

But I want to show a dropdown list of all the emails the users have added, like below but with their respective emails not all of the emails.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Choice field in not a correct option.
Django provides Emailfield in models. Use this and during get api call filter model by user id. (If user can have multiple email address, otherwise you can also define one-to-one field.)

Your model should look like:

```
class AuthUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = models.EmailField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(model=UserModel, ...)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

In case of one to one email id:

```
Class UserModel:
    name = ...
    other_fields = ...
    email = ....
```

And apply filter based on your requirement.